# How to prove the flat region for density of states $D(\epsilon)$ in tight binding electron model in 3D

Tags: solid-state-physics, geometry, density-of-states

The density of states for tight binding electron, $D(\epsilon)$, with respect to $\epsilon$(electron energy) followed an inverse cosine, a flat region ,and inverse cosine function in 3D.

It was easy to show from the math the two inverse cosine curves. However, I had a hard time to show in math that there's a region where $D(\epsilon)$  was flat.

Could you prove the flat region for density of states $D(\epsilon)$ in tight binding electron model in 3D, please?

[image]

The code which generates the above statistical distribution was shown below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.uniform(-1,1,1000000)
y = np.random.uniform(-1,1,1000000)
z = np.random.uniform(-1,1,1000000)
c = -2*(np.cos(np.pi *x )+np.cos(np.pi *y )+np.cos(np.pi *z ))
out_a=[]

for i in range(-600,600):
    out_a.append( np.sum( ((i-1)/100<c) & (c <(i/100))  )   )

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([i/100 for i in range(-600,600)],out_a)
plt.show()
```